# html5 fillStyle does not work. shows black regardless of whatever value that i pass it into. What did I do wrong?

Tags: html5-canvas

why fillStyle does not work in the code?
I console.log the variable that i passed in. 
It shows correctly. 
though, it still shows a black square instead of the color I would like to pass it into.
What did I do wrong?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('tetris');
const draw2D = canvas.getContext("2d");


const ROW = 20;
const COL = 10;
//draw2D.fillStyle = '#000';
const strColor = "#FFFFFF";
const color = "#000000";
draw2D.scale(20, 20);

function drawSquare(x, y, bgColor, lineColor) {
    console.log('bg color is: ' + bgColor);
    draw2D.fillStyle = bgColor;
    draw2D.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    console.log('line color is: ' + lineColor);
    draw2D.strokeColor = lineColor;
    draw2D.strokeRect(x, y, 1, 1);
};

drawSquare(0, 0, color, strColor);
```

```html
<canvas id="tetris"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're filling a rect 1 unit large and then stroking it with the default line width of 1 unit so the stroke is completely covering the fill

Also you wrote `strokeColor` instead of `strokeStyle`

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('tetris');
const draw2D = canvas.getContext("2d");


const ROW = 20;
const COL = 10;
//draw2D.fillStyle = '#000';
const strColor = "red";
const color = "green";
draw2D.scale(20, 20);

function drawSquare(x, y, bgColor, lineColor) {
    console.log('bg color is: ' + bgColor);
    draw2D.fillStyle = bgColor;
    draw2D.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    console.log('line color is: ' + lineColor);
    draw2D.lineWidth = 0.1;
    draw2D.strokeStyle = lineColor;
    draw2D.strokeRect(x, y, 1, 1);
};

drawSquare(0, 0, color, strColor);
```

```html
<canvas id="tetris"></canvas>
```